# Using fixtures for Event testing in Qunit

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

I'm using fixtures which means my markup is generate AFTER the JS I'm testing runs. This means that if I have `$('.something').click();` that event never gets mapped, because Qunit hasn't run yet to create **'.something'** so my original JS can't find this element to properly bind this event.

*I've found two solutions:*

**1.** Hardcode my markup next to my fixture

```
<!-- FIXTURES -->
<div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
<button class="btn-warning">text</button>
```

**2.** Add my event JS INTO my unit test.

```
var $fixture = $('#qunit-fixture');
$fixture.append('<button class="btn-warning">');
$('btn-warning').click(// Run Stuff);
// Test Code
```

Neither one of these options seem like good practice to me. The first one is preferable since it keeps things separate, but could easily get bloated. The second one introduces problems for obvious reasons as I'm no longer testing the code I'm actually using.

Here is a fiddle with a functioning [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kJR63/)

**Is this possible? What is considered best practice?**

Comment: I guess you could bind your elements using delegation and inject your fixture into the document as otherwise you would meed to be able to pass in the context of the fixture for your code binding to work. click method is a bit old school, I would suggest looking into the on method instead http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @gillesc Thanks for the reply. If I were to delegate there aren't any parent nodes to delegate to using fixtures. The next thing up is the document. Or perhaps I'm misunderstanding. And I agree about .on vs. .click. I was using that simply for brevity.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Events Failing To Trigger In QUnit Tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355456/events-failing-to-trigger-in-qunit-tests)